# Mostrar texto de base de datos en un textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea

Quiero saber como puedo tomar este texto consultado desde la base de datos y llevarlo a un textarea. Le deje los dos link por si desean ver el proceso. Muchas gracias de antemano.

https://biblia.cartelesparafacebook.com/verse.php?ref=01001001
Este es el primer codigo (Donde se muestra el texto consultado desde la bd)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<?php

$id = $_GET['ref'];

require 'connect_bible.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `t_asv` where id = '$id'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th>
                     <th>Libro</th>
                     <th>Capitulo</th>
                     <th>Versiculo</th>
                     <th>Texto</th>
                </tr>";
                
    // output data of each row   <td> <a href='https://biblia.cartelesparafacebook.com/crear?".$row["t"]."'>Crear Postal</a> </td>
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>" . $row['id']. "</td>
                <td>" . $row['b']. "</td>
                <td>" . $row['c']. "</td>
                <td>" . $row['v']. "</td>
                <td>" . $row['t']. "</td>
                <td width='300'><a href=create.php?ref=".$row['id']." title='Ver la ficha completa'>Create Image</a></td>

            </tr>";



//$btext = $row["t"];

    }
    echo "</table>";
      
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

https://biblia.cartelesparafacebook.com/create.php?ref=01001001
Y este es el segundo codigo (Donde se muestra el formulario y es donde quiero agregar el texto. Ahi es donde se estara creando la imagen)

```html
<form id="create-form" method="post" action="/php/create.php">
    
    <div id="pozter" style="background-color:<?=$_bg?>;">
        <div id="pozter-pattern">
            <div id="pozter-frame">
                <textarea id="text" name="poster_text" rows="5" maxlength="239" style="color:<?=$_ft?>;" placeholder="Escribe aqui tu texto!"><?php echo "Hola" ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    
    <div id="customizenew">
        <div class="customize-section customize-section-social">
            <a class="btn pink" id="random-design">Diseño Random</a>
            <a class="btn" id="create-btn">Listo, Crear!</a>            
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.